# How to create a schema on Google BigQuery from App Engine in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

We are attempting to create a table and define the schema on Google BigQuery from a Python app on Google AppEngine.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition) from Google's documentation demonstrates commands to set the schema that look like this:

```
# Set the table schema
    table.schema = (
        bigquery.SchemaField('Name', 'STRING'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Age', 'INTEGER'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('Weight', 'FLOAT'),
    )
```

[Per this Github example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/snippets.py), these commands require this library:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

However, when run this import command on AppEngine, we receive the error "module cloud not found."

Is this library not available on App Engine? If not, how do we create a table and define the schema on-demand from App Engine in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the Google Cloud Client Library isn't supported on App Engine standard ([issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1893)). You will need to use the [Google APIs Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/bigquery/v2) instead. You can [use this sample project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/bigquery) to see how to get started with BigQuery on App Engine.

See also:

- [Reference for creating a table with the APIs Client Library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/python/latest/bigquery_v2.tables.html)